# zsh permission denied while setting path for grails 2.5.6 and groovy 2.4.q0

Tags: grails, groovy

./zshrc file:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12)

export GROOVY_HOME=$($HOME/groovy-2.4.10)
export PATH=$PATH:$GROOVY_HOME/bin
```

error in terminal:

```
/.zshrc:3: permission denied: /$HOME/groovy-2.4.10
```

also i am not able to install any

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `$(...)`:

```sh
export GROOVY_HOME=$($HOME/groovy-2.4.10)
```

should be

```
export GROOVY_HOME=$HOME/groovy-2.4.10
```

`$(...)` tries to execute the code in the parens and return its output. But you want to point `GROOVY_HOME` to a folder, not execute the folder (which you can't, hence the error). For setting `JAVA_HOME` you do need the `$(...)` cause you run the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command and assign its output to `JAVA_HOME`.